# MySQL-python: SELECT returns 'long' instead of the query

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-python

I'm having a problem with running a select query, using `mysql-python`, on an established database.  The issue is that a number, what `Python` refers to as a `long`, is returned instead of the data queried- it should be noted that this number corresponds to the number of records which should be returned (I logged into the database and ran the query from `MySQL` to make sure).

Here is the code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(db = 'testdb', user='testuser', passwd='test', host='localhost', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
dbc = db.cursor()
result = dbc.execute("""SELECT %s FROM example_movie""", ('title',))
urls = [row[0] for row in result]
```

The last bit of code, `urls = [row[0] for row in result]` is to put everything into a list.

The error looks like this:

```
 TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable
```

When I have python `print result` it returns:

```
('RESULT:', 52L)
```

When I enclose `result` like `str(result)` it just returns the number `52` (not `long`)

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value from `dbc.execute` is not the results of the select; I believe it is the number of rows in the results. In order to get the actual results you need to call one of the `fetch` methods. See documentation [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples).

You should update your code to read:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(db = 'testdb', user='testuser', passwd='test', host='localhost', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)
dbc = db.cursor()
row_count = dbc.execute("""SELECT title FROM example_movie""")
results = dbc.fetchall()
urls = [row[0] for row in result]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to respond!  When I execute this it just prints a big list of `[u'title,...., u'title]`.  Is there a way to actually get the titles of these movies?

Comment: Actually!  If I just do `dbc.execute("""SELECT title FROM example_movie""")` that makes it work! (As opposed to the method I was using).  I'll mark your answer as accept! Feel free to add this bit into it.

Comment: @FortyLashes, one can not parametrize column names, the parameters become string literals, and you see them in the output.